# Android Eclipse setting on click listener error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android.. in a video tutorial I watch the guy writing a code and compiling it with no any error.. but when the same code I type gives me error.. don't know why..
Well.. Layout xml file is ok.. there is a error in java file.. whenever I add to a onclicklistener method to a button... it does not give any error in the code section but when I compile it it shows an error.. that application XXX has stopped unexpectedly. pleas try again.

code is here..

```
package com.abrosoft.trycommand;
import java.util.Random;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText input;
TextView display;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    Button cmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCmd);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcmd);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etinput);

 //if I delete this SetOnClickListener method.. it runs ok..
 //I get xml layout on screen of emulator.. but with this method..it doesnot run
cmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //even I write any lines of code which should perform any action on button
        //click is giving same error
    }
});

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }

}
```

}

here is my xml file code:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="25dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.abrosoft.trycommand.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="type a command"
    android:id="@+id/etinput"
    android:inputType="text"
     />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    >
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bCmd"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Command"
        />
    <ToggleButton 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tgB"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        />
</LinearLayout>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:id="@+id/tvcmd"
    />
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Go to your logcat and find the stack trace.  Post that here.

Comment: how to find stack trace?? what is actually stack trace..! sorry im new in android

Comment: A stack trace is a debug message written to a log that includes what the exception was and what function and line number it occurred on.  It should include all parent functions as well.  Look in the log and search for the word exception.

Comment: it says.. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: `07-17 11:49:40.792: W/dalvikvm(2219): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb60014f0)`

Comment: `07-17 11:49:40.802: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`
`07-17 11:49:40.802: E/AndroidRuntime(2219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abrosoft.trycommand/com.abrosoft.trycommand.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`
these are the exceptions i guess

Comment: That's the start of it.  It tells you that you dereferenced a null pointer.  The data below it tells you where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the condition

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

Also remove the PlaceHolder Class

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }
```

and change the `setContentView()` method of `OnCreate(Bundle savedInstances)` to

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Comment the below section in your code and then try to run.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

from the onCreate(Bundle) method.
It will help

Comment: To make it simple remove  

/***public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }

}**/ 

and also change the 

setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

Comment: My pleasure It helped.. :)
Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Put below code inside `onCreateView`

```
    Button cmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCmd);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcmd);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etinput);

 //if I delete this SetOnClickListener method.. it runs ok..
 //I get xml layout on screen of emulator.. but with this method..it doesnot run
cmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //even I write any lines of code which should perform any action on button
        //click is giving same error
    }
});
```

Change `onCreateView` to:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

   Button cmd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bCmd);
    display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvcmd);
    input = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etinput);

  //if I delete this SetOnClickListener method.. it runs ok..
  //I get xml layout on screen of emulator.. but with this method..it doesnot run
 cmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //even I write any lines of code which should perform any action on button
        //click is giving same error
    }
   });

   return rootView;

}
```

Comment: onCreateView method do I have to create that method?

Comment: it's there in PlaceholderFragment class inside same Activity.

Comment: when I write line `Button cmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCmd);` it gives error showing that cannot make static reference to non-static method

Comment: check my edit. Write (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bCmd);. call findViewById on rootView object

Comment: well it just ran...!! but with a blank white screen layout? :(

Comment: no buttons no textviews... not any object is on screen..!!